# Differnt PNG encoding?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, images

Using [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)'s interface tonight, was given the below error when putting together [Windows 7 in Compatibility Mode options on Windows 7 Enterprise](https://superuser.com/questions/588325/windows-7-in-compatibility-mode-options-on-windows-7-enterprise):

[image]

Problem being, it was a PNG I was trying to upload. Opening it (successfully) in Windows Server 2008's mspaint.exe, and resaving as a JPG allowed upload, but what was the problem with the PNG? File can be found at http://wikisend.com/download/128434/Windows_7_Compatibility_Dialog.png apparently until July 26, 2013. Are there any logs that can be checked for a possible bug, or could this message be clarified to state what about the PNG is non-complaint, should this be the case?

Comment: It probably just didn't download correctly, and so the file was corrupted.

Comment: If you want to use an image from the web, you have to select the option **From the web**.

Comment: Upload worked for me as well. Maybe just a temporary hiccup at imgur?

Comment: Paul - I did all the usual basic troubleshooting. Cached page refresh, non-cache refresh, browser restart - No help. @Oliver Salzburg - Not sure how this is relevant... I cannot type/c&p anything into the box that is currently filled in the screenshot provided. Only able to fill the box with anything through use of the file browse dialog, precluding pebkac in the scenario. I uploaded image seperately just in case it was helpful (for nhinkle's purpose, or to aid logs inspection to figure out why this happened, and if there is any preventative measures that could be implemented for future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upload the image just fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks nhinkle. Guess, as you seemly also proved, what @Daniel Beck stated seems very likely